# MYSQL Echo Value only once from multible columns

Tags: mysql, echo, unique, multiple-columns

I would like print out a list of names, each name only once.
The Problem: I have two different columns with names in them, yet I want to display each name only once, not depending on the column.
I am going to echo the result with PHP, so also loop's or other PHP actions are possible if there is no MYSQL only solution.

To visualise an example: (I also have an ID column as shown below)

```
ID     |Name1  |  Name2
-------|-------|-------
01     |  A    |   B
02     |  A    |   C
03     |  B    |   A
```

As seen above there are the same names in both columns, yet I want to get each name only once.

Locking like this (for example):

```
(List:)
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do it:

```
select distinct name
from (
    select Name1 name from table_name
    union all
    select Name2 name from table_name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   select distinct(name) from (select a.name1 as name from tablename as a
    union select b.name2 as name from tablename as b)name;
```